# Python equivalent of Matlab bsplinepolytraj function?

Tags: python, matlab, spline

Good morning everyone,
this is my first question so I apologize in advance for any kind of mistake.

Let me explain my problem: I need to generate a trajectory for a robotic arm from a set of waypoints. In Matlab I used the function bsplinepolytraj, but now I want to run the code in Python and I can't find an equivalent function.
What I am looking for should be able to give me the same values in output, namely position, velocity and acceleration.

Can you help me with this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking into this DRAKE tool ? I doubt there is a hard equivalent to the matlab function but they seem to do something in the realm of what you need in Python.

https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.trajectories.html#

Otherwise, and if you know how the matlab function works, you can try scipy B-spline function to implement the matlab functionality.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.BSpline.html

If you do an exact matlab replica, don't hesitate to share it via github if you want. I'm pretty sure it will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
Actually I found this tool, where the functions return a trajectory instance (position, velocity, acceleration):
https://petercorke.github.io/robotics-toolbox-python/arm_trajectory.html#
The only thing missing is figuring out which function to use by having a set of waypoints to then plot the desired trajectory..

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really need help. Unfortunately, the functions I found in the toolbox don't seem to help me because I have a set of waypoints as my starting data. 
So I want to try a different question: how can I generate a trajectory for a robotic arm from a set of waypoints? I found this other link (https://github.com/yeshg/waypointTrajectory/blob/master/main.py), do you think the function *waypointTrajectory*  could suit me better?

Comment: The function waypointTrajectory seems to do what you need. It even uses spline-related functions to do the interpolation between points. I would try to adapt that for your use. It does't seem too hard.

Answer (score 0):

After days of research and tests, I found this repository on Git that proposes several solutions to the path planning problem.

https://github.com/AtsushiSakai/PythonRobotics/tree/master/PathPlanning

I found it very useful, I hope other people can use it too.
Cheers!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. 
Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. 
You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).